# Valor em real (R$) para número em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz um script para transformar um campo que recebe valor em real (com . e ,) para número, o problema é que não funciona muito bem. Coloquem esse valor no campo R$ 123.456.789.123,11 e vejam a resposta, eu queria receber esse número: 123456789123.11 mas ta retornando esse 123456.789.123.11

```js
<script>
function campo6_10Up() {
    var campo1 = $('#campo1').val();
    // transforma para numero
    campo1 = formataNumero(campo1);
    console.log(campo1);    
}
function formataNumero(n) {
    n = n.replace('R$ ', '');
    if (n === "") {
        n = 0;
    } else {
        n = n.replace(".", "");
        n = n.replace(",", ".");
    }
    return n;
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="text" class="site_form" id="campo1" onkeyup="campo6_10Up()">
```

Onde errei?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mude `n = n.replace(".","");` por `n = n.split('.').join("");`

```js
function campo6_10Up() {
 var campo1 = $('#campo1').val();
 // transforma para numero
 campo1 = formataNumero(campo1);
 console.log(campo1);
}
function formataNumero(n) {
 n = n.replace('R$ ','');
 if(n === ""){
  n =  0;
 }else{
        n = n.split('.').join("");
 n = n.replace(",",".");
 }
 return n;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="text" class="site_form" id="campo1" onkeyup="campo6_10Up()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho a utilizar o método `toLocaleString()`, onde o mesmo retorna uma string com uma representação sensível a linguagem deste número.

No uso básico sem a especificação de uma localização, o método retornará uma string formatada com a localização e as opções padrão.

```
var numero = 3500;
console.log(numero.toLocaleString()); // Mostra "3,500" se a localização for U.S. English
```

Este exemplo mostra algumas variações de formatos de números localizados. A fim de obter o formato da linguagem utilizada na interface do usuário da sua aplicação, tenha certeza de especificar a língua (e possivelmente algumas línguas reservas) usando o argumento `locales`:

```
var numero = 123456.789;

// O alemão usa vírgula como separador de decimal e ponto para milhares
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
// → 123.456,789

// O árabe usa dígitos Árabes Orientais em muitos países que falam árabe
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('ar-EG'));
// → ١٢٣٤٥٦٫٧٨٩

// A Índia usa separadores de milhares/cem mil/dez milhões
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
// → 1,23,456.789

// A chave de extensão nu requer um sistema de numeração, ex. decimal chinês
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('zh-Hans-CN-u-nu-hanidec'));
// → 一二三,四五六.七八九

// Quando informada uma língua sem suporte, como balinês,
// inclua uma língua reseva, neste caso indonésio
console.log(numero.toLocaleString(['ban', 'id']));
// → 123.456,789
```

Os resultados obtidos por `toLocaleString` pode ser personalizado usando o argumento `options`:

```
var numero = 123456.789;

// informando um formato de moeda
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));
// → 123.456,79 €

// o yen japonês não tem uma unidade menor
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }))
// → ￥123,457

// limitando a três dígitos significativos
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }));
// → 1,23,000
```

Answer (score 0):

Com replace usando regex você elimina tudo o que não for número e vírgula, e mais um replace troca a vírgula por ponto:

```
-> n = R$ 123.456.789.123,11
-> n.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '')
-> 123456789123,11
-> n.replace(",", ".")
-> 123456789123.11
```

Teste:

```js
function campo6_10Up() {
    var campo1 = $('#campo1').val();
    // transforma para numero
    campo1 = formataNumero(campo1);
    console.log(campo1);    
}
function formataNumero(n) {
    return n.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '').replace(",", ".");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="site_form" id="campo1" onkeyup="campo6_10Up()">
```